# Unistalled usb drivers Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, usb, drivers, format

The story begins when I formated my pc. Everything was perfect except a small problem. The screen was going black for a second and the usb connected sound was made.

I googled the problem and found this forum : https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-performance/computer-makes-disconnect-sound-screen-flashes/82078c25-606f-4021-a176-6e30ec81130c

In the answers there are 3 methods. I tried the second one without even thinking about it (huge mistake). Long story short I unistalled the usb drivers. Now I'm left with a computer which I can't control. I even tried to use a bootable usb but that wouldn't work because there's nothing to drive it.

Is there any way that I have accidentally deleted data from the motherboard and I can't boot from bootable flash drive?

I'm stuck right now and can't do anything about it. I don't know if that helps but my computer has a ps2 port.

Any advice?

Comment: But booting from a USB stick doesn't use your Windows drivers...

Comment: I know! But it doesn't work I am really confused

Comment: @Neo have you tried booting in safe mode or recovery mode and doing a repair-installation

Comment: Use System Restore to rollback to before this was done.

Comment: @Madhubala I can't get it to open bios or boot menu. I'll try disconnecting the hdd and boot from the bootable drive. Then I will reconnect the drive and start the repair-installation

Comment: @harrymc I can't get it to open safe or repair mode

Answer (score 0):

If you can get the computer to boot from USB, I suggest doing
[Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

If USB can't boot from bootable media, I suggest taking the computer to a repair-shop.